# dynamically add parameter to the start URL

Tags: ios, cordova, uiwebview, cordova-plugins

Before using Cordova, I used to add a dynamic parameter that detects the phone OS language and put it in the URL, so I can view the website page in the user's language.

```
NSString * language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://mywebsite.com/?language=%@", language];
```

But using Cordova forces me to load a static URL, is there anything I can do to insert the language parameter to the URL when the app starts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [plugin](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html) to detect the phone language with the code you are already using and on the success callback redirect to your website using javascript like this:

`window.location.href = 'http://mywebsite.com/?language='+pluginResult;`

You can also add this in your `AppDelegate.m` inside the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, right before the return

`NSString * language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
self.viewController.startPage = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://mywebsite.com/?language=%@", language];`

Comment: My app localization process depends on a parameter in the url that tells the php function how to translate. I really need it in the URL.

Comment: But you are loading a local URL, you can't load local PHP in your Cordova app. You can use javascript to redirect to your online server, but it's not a good practice to load websites inside Cordova apps and Apple might not approve your app

Comment: I'm already loading my remote server url on Cordova! I just put my website URL and it is working fine, and Apple already approved my app my friend.

Comment: so, what is your problem?

Comment: My problem is that I can't change the website URL to add the phone language parameter on the app start, it is static, and I was asking if there is a way to dynamically change Cordova static URL to add the language parameter when the app starts! Means if there is a way to override Cordova's URL and modify it, just like we do with normal UIWebView.

Comment: Just create the plugin that tells you the language and on the callback of the plugin redirect to your online url with window.location.href = 'yourUrlWithTheLang'

Comment: Second option was the best, tested and working. Thanks man :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with part of @jcesarmobile's answer. But to detect user language you need not have to develop new plugin i guess as a [globalization plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-globalization) is already available for this purpose.

So hopefully you can use plugin to get the preferred language and use the approach suggested by @jcesarmobile to redirect to your website using javascript like this:

`window.location.href = 'http://mywebsite.com/?language='+preferredLanguage;`

Hope it helps.